# iOS - sending URL through mail showing different behavior in simulator and device

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, smtp

A strange behaviour is happening when I am trying to send mail from device.

I have used SMTP to send mail from background in my app and I have to send user's current location URL in app.

Now, when I send it from simulator it works almost fine and i got this url -

https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&q=0.000000,0.000000

But, when I send it from device it sends the url like this -

https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&q".719793,75.877068

The code I used to make url is

```
-(NSString*)LocationLinkTosentInMail
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [self getLocation];
    NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.latitude];
    NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.longitude];

    NSLog(@"*dLatitude : %@", latitude);
    NSLog(@"*dLongitude : %@",longitude);


    NSString *currentLocationURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&q=%@,%@",latitude,longitude];

    return currentLocationURL;

}


 NSURL *locationURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self LocationLinkTosentInMail]]];
```

In SMTP mail function, I use this code to make dictionary

```
NSDictionary *plain_text_part = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                         @"text/plain\r\n\tcharset=UTF-8;\r\n\tformat=flowed", kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                                         [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My Location is: %@",locationURL], kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,
        @"quoted-printable", kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,
        nil];
```

Can anyone suggest me if any change required in code?

Why simulator and device are showing different behavior to send this url?

Comment: Use HTML Tag and in mail body enable HTML in iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever we have to send `URL` thourgh `smtp` in objective c, we should always careful about the special character of url.

Finally i got the solution of my problem in the `encoding process`.

the Encoding in the `NSDictionary` object, I changed it from **`quoted-printable`**
 to **`8bit`** .

Now `dictionary` obj would be:

```
 NSDictionary *plain_text_part = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 @"text/plain", kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                            strMessage, kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,
                                 @"8bit", kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,
                                 nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use HTML Tag and in mail body enable HTML in iOS

[emailDialog setMessageBody:mailBody isHTML:YES];

[Check this page for href tag!](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)

Comment: For MFMialComposer this method can work but for SMTP, it's not working BTY thanks....